# Change the size of header panel in lattice plot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I want to change the `header panel size` and also the `font size` of the `text` within that. Here is an example:

```
library(lattice)
dat <-data.frame(a=(rnorm(50)),b=(rnorm(50)),c=(c(rep("first",25),rep("second",25))))
xyplot(a~b|c, data=dat,par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="gray")))
```

Basically I need the size of the `gray area` and also `"first"` and `"second"` font size to be larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `par.strip.text=` argument, which accepts a list with components specifying any of `cex`, `font`, `lines`, and `lineheight` (the latter giving the space between any multi-line strip titles).

For example, try this:

```
stripParams <- list(cex=2, lines=1.5)
xyplot(a~b|c, data=dat,
       par.strip.text = stripParams,
       par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="gray")))
```

[image]